# Scrollreveal.js adding mysterious padding/space to website once window is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Noticed that when I resize the browser window on [this](http://yousaypotato.com/) website a heap of space is added to the bottom, just below the footer.

Disabling the `Scrollreveal.js` cures the problem, but I want to keep the animations.

The bug is noticeable in Chrome / Safari, Firefox seems to work fine.

I've validated the site but still get the error in these browsers, Has anyone any ideas? I can't even Inspect the space thats generated, also Im using foundation 5 for the framework, maybe something I've changed?

Comment: Removed an animation effect on a div that was using "position:relative" and the problem was solved, I'll try recoding that smarter, hopefully all should be well.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with the background that is applied in that area:

Try adding the following CSS to your stylesheet:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
   #contact .columns {
      z-index: 2;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I disabled the animation effect for the "peeled potato" image that was using "position:relative" for some reason that was causing the white space to be added, Not an Ideal fix, but it will have to do for now.